# How to fix "Unterminated regular expression literal" error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I did check these multiple questions on SO, but so far none has the answer. Very simple regex that giving error "Unterminated regular expression literal" near the escaped dot. Regex should match `./images/`.

```
const regex = new RegExp(/\.\/images\/);
const options = {
    files: [
        './style/_styles.scss'
      ],
    from: [regex],
    to: ['./../dist/primeng-lib/images/']
  };
```

Comment: Your regular expression ends with `\/`, which means that the last `/` is interpreted as *part* of the expression and not the end delimiter. The `new RegExp()` function should be passed a string anyway, not a regular expression literal. If you use a literal you don't need the constructor.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks, that's a good point about Regex constructor!

Comment: `const regex = /\.\/images\//;`, it will match `./images/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first line, you forgot the closing regex delimiter.

Change this:

```
const regex = new RegExp(/\.\/images\/);
```

To this

```
const regex = new RegExp(/\.\/images\//);
```